# GhostScript PDF/A conformance

Tags: ghostscript, pdfa

There seems to be an error in the GhostScript PDF/A generation.

When you generate a PDF/A document via GhostScript, when you click on Adobe Reader, there is a Conformance tab which displays:

"Conformance:
Standard: PDF/A-1B
ISO Name: ISO 19005-1
Status: not yet verified"

It is a hit and miss affair. When you generate the same PDF file via command-line, it also gives:

"The PDF you are currently viewing does not identify itself as compliant with any standard" sometimes

I used command-line:

gswin32c -dPDFX -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy0 -sOutputFile=resu.tpdf xxx.ps PDFA_DEF.ps

Any ideas how to make it always show the conformance message instead of non-conformance?

Comment: Which version of Ghostscript are you using? Type `gswin32c -v` and report the results. -- Also, what is the complete content of your *PDFX_DEF.ps*  file? Can you post it? Note, that what is shipped by Ghostscript is only a sample of a *PDFX_def.ps* -- you may need to adapt it to your own environment....

Comment: Can you tell me how to adapt it to my environment? I don't know how to adapt it.

Comment: Did you read my comment *fully*? Also the part about what I asked you to 'report' and 'post'?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confusing "feature" of Adobe Reader X (and perhaps earlier versions).  "Status: not yet verified" makes it sound like Reader could verify PDF/A conformance.  However, to verify conformance using an Adobe product, you need Acrobat Pro:

> The Standards panel is present in all versions (Std, Pro and even
>   Reader). However, Verify Compliance functionality is only present in
>   Acrobat Pro.

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7b40.w.html#WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7b3d.w.

So the presence of "not yet verified" in Reader does NOT mean that the PDF/A is not correct.

I don't have Acrobat Pro. It would be interesting to know if, once verified by Acrobat Pro, a document opened in Reader would show as Verified.

Answer (score 2):

If you believe you have found a Ghostscritp bug then we would appreciate it if you would raise a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com.

However this has most likely already been fixed and I would suggest that you try the current code from the Git repository.

If not then please raise a bug report, supply the source file and the command line you were using, and let us know exactly how you are checking the conformance.